# Evaluation of lazy arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, lazy-evaluation, fog

I have a problem with the following piece of code using Fog to get a list of servers from Rackspace - I am concatenating servers new generation with servers old generation.

```
def servers()
  servers = @service.servers
  servers_old = @service_old.servers
  size = servers.length + servers_old.length # line 4
  all_servers = servers + servers_old # line 5
  servers = all_servers.sort_by { |k| k.name}
  return servers
end
```

If the fourth line is commented out, the method is returning only the `service.servers` array. Concatenation in the fifth line does not happen. It seems to me that the arrays `service.servers` and `service_old.servers` are somehow lazy until I explicitly ask for them.

With the uncommented fourth line, the method is returning concatenated arrays, which is what I expect. If these arrays are lazy is there any recommended method for evaluating them? Right now I am just using  `length` but I don't really need it. Any hint/link for some specific documentation?

Comment: Arrays are not lazy in ruby. What is your `@service` object?

Comment: Fog collections are lazy loaded.  Hold please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.all` is your friend here.  `Fog` collections generally have an `all` method that fixes the issue with lazy loading that you are having.  Instead of `@service.servers`, use this:

```
servers = @service.servers.all
```

and

```
servers_old = @service_old.servers.all
```

Comment: .all works great. Can you share some info how I could deduct this using some introspection in Ruby?

Comment: Fog is kind of a fickle beast sometimes, I've just spent a lot of time reading/writing stuff in Fog, so I've learned some of its nuances.  The best way to find out what methods something has that are unique though is something like `@service.servers.methods - Object.methods` which will reveal all of the methods on the `Fog::Rackspace::Servers` collection that are not also part of a standard Ruby `Object`.